# "Ask Question" interstitial notification doesn't show a "proceed" link on Firefox 3.6.13

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, firefox

When I tried to post a question this morning on Stack Overflow using Firefox 3.6 on Mac OS X 10.6, I could not proceed to the actual form because the link never showed up. The only reason I can tell you guys right now is because I'm using Chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what has caused this (although I couldn't reproduce it); if I'm correct this will be fixed in the next build.

Please let us know if you still see this tomorrow. Thanks!